# What is the purpose of "EnableSubscriptionPartitioning" property in an Azure Service Bus Topic?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

When it comes to partitioning in an Azure Service Bus Topic, there are two properties: `EnablePartitioning` and `EnableSubscriptionPartitioning`.

It is very clear to me what `EnablePartitioning` property does. Based on my understanding of this property, essentially when this property is set to true, the topic in question will be partitioned across multiple message brokers.

What I am not able to find is any concrete information on `EnableSubscriptionPartitioning` property. The [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.servicebus/namespaces/topics?view=azuresmps-3.7.0#TopicProperties) I looked at simply describes this property as:

> Value that indicates whether partitioning is enabled or disabled.

Furthermore when I create a topic with this property set to true (and enable partitioning property set to false) a topic is created for me with `118784 MB` in size (`MaxSizeInMegabytes` property). Here's the response XML I get when I fetch topic's properties.

```
<entry xml:base="https://namespace.servicebus.windows.net/$Resources/topics?api-version=2016-07">
  <id>https://namespace.servicebus.windows.net/gauravtesttopic?api-version=2016-07</id>
  <title type="text">gauravtesttopic</title>
  <published>2017-08-18T02:00:12Z</published>
  <updated>2017-08-18T02:00:18Z</updated>
  <author><name>namespace</name></author>
  <link rel="self" href="../gauravtesttopic?api-version=2016-07"/>
  <content type="application/xml">
    <TopicDescription xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <DefaultMessageTimeToLive>P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S</DefaultMessageTimeToLive>
      <MaxSizeInMegabytes>118784</MaxSizeInMegabytes>
      <RequiresDuplicateDetection>false</RequiresDuplicateDetection>
      <DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow>PT10M</DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow>
      <EnableBatchedOperations>true</EnableBatchedOperations>
      <SizeInBytes>0</SizeInBytes>
      <FilteringMessagesBeforePublishing>false</FilteringMessagesBeforePublishing>
      <IsAnonymousAccessible>false</IsAnonymousAccessible>
      <AuthorizationRules></AuthorizationRules>
      <Status>Active</Status>
      <CreatedAt>2017-08-18T02:00:11.5270915Z</CreatedAt>
      <UpdatedAt>2017-08-18T02:00:18.087Z</UpdatedAt>
      <AccessedAt>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</AccessedAt>
      <SupportOrdering>true</SupportOrdering>
      <CountDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2011/06/servicebus">
        <d2p1:ActiveMessageCount>0</d2p1:ActiveMessageCount>
        <d2p1:DeadLetterMessageCount>0</d2p1:DeadLetterMessageCount>
        <d2p1:ScheduledMessageCount>0</d2p1:ScheduledMessageCount>
        <d2p1:TransferMessageCount>0</d2p1:TransferMessageCount>
        <d2p1:TransferDeadLetterMessageCount>0</d2p1:TransferDeadLetterMessageCount>
      </CountDetails>
      <SubscriptionCount>0</SubscriptionCount>
      <AutoDeleteOnIdle>P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S</AutoDeleteOnIdle>
      <EnablePartitioning>false</EnablePartitioning>
      <IsExpress>false</IsExpress>
      <EntityAvailabilityStatus>Available</EntityAvailabilityStatus>
      <EnableSubscriptionPartitioning>true</EnableSubscriptionPartitioning>
      <EnableExpress>false</EnableExpress>
    </TopicDescription>
  </content>
</entry>
```

The problem I run with this is when I try to update the topic, I get an error message from the service complaining about invalid size. Because the topic is not partitioned, the size should be one of the following: 1GB, 2GB, 3GB, 4GB or 5GB.

Any insights into this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can check the dcoumentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh780749.aspx. There is upper limit of 5 gb basically multiple of 1024

Comment: Thanks! While the link you mentioned does talk about 1-5GB size, it doesn't talk about this property. Plus why a topic is created with 116GB size is not mentioned there.

Comment: Max SIze can be  80 Gb in case partition is enabled. Might be some bug found :)